# Retrieving data from two tables at once with one table referencing the other

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two table as follows:

**TABLE 1:**

```
ID Code Detail
1  45   Yes
2  46   No
```

**AND TABLE 2:**

```
Code Detail1 Detail2
45   No    23
22   Yes   34
```

Is it possible to *select all **FROM TABLE 2** where detail = YES AND where TABLE 1 contains Code and says Yes*?

**i.e. query result should be**:

```
Code Detail Detail
45   No     23
22   Yes    34
```

Thanks.

Comment: You said you want to select all where detail = yes, but then your result example has a detail = No... Also, why/how do you have two fields with the same name in the same table?

Comment: Yes, it is returning that based on being contained in the first table, i.e. data is retrieved from second table when it is yes on `table 1` and code exists in `table 1`

Comment: then how did you get two result rows in your example, when only one row in Table1 has detail = yes?

Comment: Because the **retrieval is done from the second table**.

Comment: You have 2 `Detail` columns in Table 2...explain.

Comment: Sorry, it's just an example i.e. Detail1, Detail2

Comment: Having two ```Detail``` columns is completely valid, even without aliases as they can be referenced by index number.

Comment: So, you want to select them if `Table1.Detail = 'Yes' OR Table2.Detail1 = 'Yes'`

Comment: if `table2.Detail1` = 'yes' OR `Table2.Code` contains the particular Code being queried and has the detail as yes, I think it should be dealing with `JOIN` statements, but I don't know how.

Comment: Why is `Code` = `22` in the result set? This implies `OR` not `AND` logic.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary That's what has been throwing me off - it doesn't seem to add up with what he is saying.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: The results are to be retrieved from TABLE 2 since TABLE 1 does not have enough details

Answer (score 3):

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f583/9

```
SELECT
    Table2.Code,
    Table2.Detail1,
    Table2.Detail2
FROM
    Table1,
    Table2
WHERE
    Table1.Detail = "Yes" OR
    (Table2.Detail1 = "Yes" AND
    Table1.Code = Table2.Code)
```

Although, my above query seems to give you the correct resultset for the example, I think that the following query better satisfies your criteria:

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f583/12

```
SELECT
    Table2.Code,
    Table2.Detail1,
    Table2.Detail2
FROM
    Table1,
    Table2
WHERE
    (Table1.Code = Table2.Code AND
    Table1.Detail = "Yes") OR
    Table2.Detail1 = "Yes"
GROUP BY
    Table1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow your question very well but this will create the table of results that you want.

```
select table2.* from table2 left join table1 on table2.code = table1.code where table2.Detail1 = 'Yes' or table1.Detail = 'Yes'
```